# QT QSS selector by part of the ID

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I can apply QSS to a QPushButton like this, by ID or all QPushButton's (with no #ID at all).

```
QPushButton#BTN_A{
  background-color: white; 
  color: #659D32;
  border: 1px solid #659D32;
  font-size: 14px; 
}

QPushButton{
  background-color: white; 
  color: #659D32;
  border: 1px solid #659D32;
  font-size: 14px; 
}
```

However I'd like to apply the QSS to all buttons that start with **#BTN**

In CSS it would be something like:

```
div[class*="test"] {
   background: #ffffff;
}
```

I've tried *QPushButton#BTN**, *QPushButton#BTN^**
At the moment I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried `QPushButton[objectName*="BTN"]`

Comment: I haven't and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
QPushButton[objectName*="BTN"]
```